# How to append row to ngrepeated elements in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, appendchild

i am having hard time while appending elements to the ng-repeat elements. Here is the fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/ukgym9f9/4/

```
app.directive("addAgendaRow", function($compile){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element,attrs,controller){
        element.on("click", function() {
            console.log("clicked on add row");
            $compile(element.parent().parent().parent().append('<tr class="add-remove-row" title="title"><td><div class="has-placeholder" placeholder="Your text Goes Here" contenteditable="true"></div></td><td class="add-remove-row"><a href="javascript:void(0);" add-agenda-row class="add" title="Add Row"></a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" remove-agenda-row class="remove" title="Remove Row"></a></td></tr>'))(scope);
        });
    }   
    }
});
```

When i click on '+', it will remove the existing rows and creates new row. How do i combat this issue ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please check your fiddle, it is not working at all. `<table>` missing?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to `$compile` this when the click event occurs. Just try [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to bubble up the DOM tree and append it e.g. to the `<table>`:

```
app.directive("addAgendaRow", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                element.on("click", function() {
                    element.closest("table").append('<tr class="add-remove-row" title="title"><td><div class="has-placeholder" placeholder="Your text Goes Here" contenteditable="true"></div></td><td class="add-remove-row"><a href="javascript:void(0);" add-agenda-row class="add" title="Add Row"></a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" remove-agenda-row class="remove" title="Remove Row"></a></td></tr>');
                });
            }   
        }
});
```

Comment: if i remove the complile, how would Angular bind click to add-row button ?